# reactivemongo - value connection is not a member of object reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I was trying to use ReactiveMongo 0.12.7 with Scala 2.11.8 to connect to MongoDB and hitting the following error:

```
value connection is not a member of object reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver
```

Dependency:

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.12.7"
```

and my code:

```
package com.some.package

// import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import reactivemongo.api.{DefaultDB, MongoConnection, MongoDriver}
import reactivemongo.bson.{BSONDocumentWriter, BSONDocumentReader, Macros, document}
import reactivemongo.core.nodeset.Authenticate

object MongoConfigReactive {
    def getMongoCredentials(mongoDbName: String = "mydb",
                            mongoUsername: String = "username",
                            mongoPassword: String = "password"): List[Authenticate] = {
        List(Authenticate(mongoDbName, mongoUsername, mongoPassword))
    }

    def getServerList(): List[String] = {
        List("cluster0-shard-00-00-server.com:27017",
             "cluster0-shard-00-01-server.com:27017",
             "cluster0-shard-00-02-server.com:27017")
    }

    def getMongoConnection(): MongoConnection = {
        val mongoDriver = MongoDriver
        mongoDriver.connection(getServerList, authentications = getMongoCredentials())
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses when using the `MongoDriver` companion object:

```
val mongoDriver = MongoDriver()
```

Alternatively, you can create a new instance of the `MongoDriver` class directly:

```
val mongoDriver = new MongoDriver
```